# iOS device doesn't receive push notifications after uploading server side code and certificate from my computer to server

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ssl

I have write a simple php script to test the apple push notification on my local machine and here it is:

```
<?php
  function sendPushNotification($token, $payload) {
    $cert = 'FooBarDev.pem';
    $passphrase = '<here is my passphrase>';
    $endpoint = 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';

    $context = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cert);
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');

    $conn = stream_socket_client($endpoint, $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $context);

    if (!$conn) {
      echo('Connection to APNs failed');
      return;
    }

    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result = fwrite($conn, $msg, strlen($msg));
    fclose($conn);

    if ($result) {
      echo('Notification sent');
    } else {
      echo('Error sending notification');
    }
  }

  $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '<here is database password>', 'foobar');
  $query = "SELECT token FROM tokens";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  $aps['alert'] = $_POST['alert'];
  $aps['badge'] = intval($_POST['badge']);
  $aps['sound'] = 'default';
  $payload['aps'] = $aps;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    sendPushNotification($row['token'], json_encode($payload));
  }
?>
```

and below is some client side code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let token = String(deviceToken).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>")).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "").stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
        let body = "token=\(token)"

        let endpoint = "http://120.25.88.119/foobar/register_token.php"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: endpoint)!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I made a request to the localhost with some post data and it worked just fine, I received notification on iPhone and iPad.

But when I upload the php script along with the certificate files, and send another request to the remote server, I got no notifications.

And here is something I have to state:
1: I have change the database query part of the php code, so it's not likely that I was querying the wrong database, fetching the wrong token, and there is tokens too in the remote database.
2: I also uploaded the certificates altogether with php files, same directory structure as on my mac.
3: I have changed the file mode to 777 both on local machine and server.

Could anybody help me? Appreciate!

Comment: follow the steps in http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2, it may help you.